# Call a rest API service from Oracle database

Tags: oracle, rest

Is it possible that when registering a record in a column with a value of 0 in an Oracle table, an API endpoint can be called to try to update said value?

I have not found a solution to implement this, the only thing I can think of is to have a service that constantly consults the database, but it does not seem very efficient to me.

Comment: What does it realy mean (@José Abraham Campos Velez) "..when registering a record in a column with a value of 0 in an Oracle table..." and what kind of rest api you would like to call. Is it Oracle or third side or ...

Comment: You'd be best served with a scheduled job that looks for rows with that column value 0 and calls the API. That way if the API isn't working nothing breaks. It'll get around to updating the values it couldn't later when the API is working again. If you attempt to trigger a call outside the database, particularly a network call, in the middle of a DML operation you risk holding a transaction forever if it stalls out, and on error if you decide to commit anyway you'll never get around to updating the record.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

1. What inserts entries in your database? Probably some kind of API (like Spring Boot) I guess? -> Implement the logic there.
2. There are Triggers in SQL which could perform such logic. As the name suggests, it gets Triggered when a certain Event is performed.

Maybe provide more Information what you really are trying to achieve. This would help to provide you with a proper solution.

Comment: yes an INSERT trigger could fire off plsql which retrieves data from a REST API via HTTPS, and then use that to set the :NEW value for your column(s)

Comment: @thatjeffsmith, if there's a network blip that stalls out the network call, you wouldn't want to be holding a transaction open indefinitely. Outcalls from the database on DML are not a great idea from a management standpoint.

Comment: well if we had time for long form replies, i'd say, think this over, if someone sends over 1k inserts, you dont' want 1k output https requests, or you'll bottleneck quickly, but the question was literally, 'is it possible' - not 'should I'